# Show/Hide Form elements based on json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I make an api call and get a json Response that looks like this:

```
{"Field":"Amount","FieldName":"Amount","FieldType":"Numeric","MaximumLength":128,"MinimumLength":0,"Options":"Mandatory"}
```

The api call Returns between 5-10 of These objects.
In my html i have the fields inside a form, and they look as follow

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Amount">Amount</label>  
<div class="col-md-4">
<input name="amount" class="form-control input-md" id="amount" type="text" placeholder="placeholder">

 </div>
 </div>
```

Now, depending on the json repsonse, i Need to show/hide different fields. Additionally, i Need to pass the min and max length, aswell as whether it's required or not ("Options":"Mandatory", in this example) Attributes to html, so the front end is already validate (obviously, further validation will be done server-side).

What's the best way to do this?

Edit:

I hide the Form Elements by using class="hidden". Also, every form element has a class that is identical to the id of the form element.

What i've tried so far is the following:

```
var ids = [];
for(var item in data) {
 ids.push(data[item]['Field']);
     $("." + ids[ids.length]).removeClass("hidden");
}
```

So in the above example, what i was hoping would happen in the first Iteration is that

```
$("." + ids[ids.length]).removeClass("hidden");
```

changes to

```
$(.Amount).removeClass("hidden");
```

and therefor show the form element.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? What was the problem?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko

I haven't tried anything yet, as i don't really know how to do it.

Comment: Then you need to google some basic tutorial because SO is not a coding service. Please read this [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko

I have just not been able to find anything that helped me, that being the reason i wrote here.

Comment: Seriously? I can't imagine you were not able to find how to show/hide elements or set attributes using jquery. [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko


The Problem i'm facing isn't as to how to show/hide Elements, it's rather how to loop through the json/Array and show/hide all Elements that i get as Response.

I've edited the question to show what i've tried so far.

Comment: I don't see any element with class `Amount` assume `amount`

Comment: Yeah that was a mistake on my part. Fixed it already in my code.

Thanks for pointing it out tho, appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```
$("." + ids[ids.length]).removeClass("hidden");
```

When you push one element to ids array the length becomes 1 and your element is in 0th position but you are accessing element in first position.

To correct it change the line to

```
$("." + ids[ids.length - 1]).removeClass("hidden");
```

Comment: This was indeed what i ended up doing. I wanted to answer my own question for people that might find this post, so i was just about to finish the code (including the adding of Attributes) and answer this post after testing.

Anyways, this is the correct answer and works. If i hadn't found out by now this definitely would have been a huge help.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

```
I ended up solving it like this:

var ids = [];
    var minlength = [];
    var maxlength = [];
    var required = [];

    for(var item in data) {

//push values into array

        ids.push(data[item]['Field']);
        maxlength.push(data[ids.length-1]['MaximumLength']);
        minlength.push(data[ids.length-1]['MinimumLength']);
        required.push(data[ids.length-1]['Options']);


//removes the class hidden and therefor shows the Element
        $("." + ids[ids.length-1]).removeClass("hidden"); 

//adds the Attribute minlength to the html element
        $("#" + ids[ids.length-1]).attr('minlength', minlength[minlength.length-1]); 

//adds the Attribute maxlengthto the html element
        $("#" + ids[ids.length-1]).attr('maxlength', maxlength[maxlength.length-1]); 

//if the value in the Array is "Mandatory", adds the Attribute "required" to the html element
        if (required[ids.length-1] == "Mandatory") {

        $("#" + ids[ids.length-1]).attr('required', "required");

        }
```